# Meteor query based on the value of elements in an array inside an object

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and mongoDB and have been searching for an answer to this question for some time without any luck.
I have multiple documents in MongoDB similar to the one below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abac4ea0c31d26804421371"),
    "Points" : [
        {
            "Value" : 6.869752766626993,
            "Time" : 1522284528946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 3.9014587731230477,
            "Time" : 1522284543946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 1.2336926618519772,
            "Time" : 1522284558946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 6.504837583667155,
            "Time" : 1522284573946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 9.824138227740864,
            "Time" : 1522284588946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 9.707480757899235,
            "Time" : 1522284603946
        },
        {
            "Value" : 4.6122167850338105,
            "Time" : 1522284618946
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I implement a query in meteor that returns an array containing all the Points from all documents with 'Time' field greater than certain value?

Comment: When you normalize your mongo data models it will be much easier to write queries. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jankapunkt has pointed out in his comment, it might be a lot easier and better if you created a new collection *Points* where each document includes only *Value* and *Time* attributes. The given example would then become seven separate documents rather than a single array.

It does nevertheless happen, that we want to query documents according to some inner values, e.g. attributes in objects in arrays.

Taken from the [mongodb documentation on querying embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arra%E2%80%A6), we can just use dot notation for this.

> If you do not know the index position of the document nested in the array, concatenate the name of the array field, with a dot (.) and the name of the field in the nested document.

Such as for your question (assuming *Points* to be the name of your collection):

```
db.points.find( { 'Points.Time': { $gte: 123412341234 } } )
```

Which looks almost identical in Meteor:

```
Points.find({ 'Points.Time': { $gte: 123412341234 } })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The collections are created by a background C code that I don't have control over. There are some association between the points arrays and some other fields in the document that we can't break to bring the points array to a collection of points. Your solution resolved my issue. Thanks again.